# Why aren't all local files displaying when using ArrayList?

Tags: android, image, arraylist

I'm downloading files with my app via an API (this is working perfectly). Later in my app I'm doing a call to my database to get the file info: id, name, location and return it as a HashMap:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> imgTitle;
```

I take the returned HashMap, extract the ArrayList and use that to populate some buttons. the array list holds the filename and file location. When the page loads the names display correctly but the images don't always load or one loads. If I go back and reenter the activity (via a button press) I'll get different images showing up. I've sent my array to the log and the file location is present and correct for all arrays. Why are only some image showing?

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> e : imgTitle.entrySet()) {
    ...
    ArrayList<String> catList = e.getValue();
    final String catTitle = catList.get(0);
    File indexImage = new File(catList.get(1));
    // add images
    ImageButton imgButton = new ImageButton(this);
    imgButton.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(indexImage));
    ...
}
```

The above is inside a method called on the onCreate. My assumption is maybe the setImageURI is too slow? Any ideas?

Prior to using the `setImageURI` I used

```
imgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_vehicle);
```

as a placeholder it was working fine. However, now I have to use a file that was downloaded and saved locally.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to decode a Bitmap from a stream, like this:

```
File indexImage = new File(catList.get(1));
InputStream imageStream = new FileInputStream(indexImage);
Bitmap backgroundImage = null;
try {
    backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    try {
        //Dispose of the temporary resources
        imageStream.close();
        imageStream = null //So that the stream is deleted on next GC
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
if (backgroundImage != null) {
    ImageButton imgButton = new ImageButton(this);
    imgButton.setImageBitmap(backgroundImage);
    backgroundImage.recycle();
}
```

*Note: This is pure speculation, I haven't tested any of this. It's simply the first solution that came to my mind*

Comment: You could also add the check after try/finally/catch block: `if(backgroundImage != null) {...}` so you don't waste your resources and time in case the stream decoding failed, I'll edit it right now.

Comment: `InputStream imageStream = new FileInputStream(indexImage);` requires a try/catch. Doing so causes anytime `imageStream` is used to throw an error that it's not initialized.

Comment: set imageStream to null to initialize it. appears to load only one image but it's empty (there is space where it would be)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't debug it without actually testing it, put a bunch of breakpoints and see what's executing and what isn't